# How do I concatenate a string with double quotes and a colon in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My macro hides rows depending on variable values (start_row and end_row).

I have this line of code:

```
Worksheets("Exhibit").Rows(""""&start_row&":"&end_row&"""").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Which for the values start_row = 1 and end_row = 5, I would want it to do the same thing as the following code:

```
Worksheets("Exhibit").Rows("1:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

I get a "Compile error: Expected: list separator or )" which highlights the ":" portion of the line, though.

How can I fix this?

Comment: VBA likes its spacing.. Adding spaces around ampersands will allow it to compile. Then heed the answer below.

Comment: Without the space, `&` is interpreted as a *type hint*, e.g. `Debug.Print TypeName(42&)` will not output `Integer` like `TypeName(42)` would. With the space, it's the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ditch the opening and closing quotes entirely:

```
Worksheets("Exhibit").Rows(start_row & ":" & end_row).Hidden = True
```

And as pointed out by [@Mark Balhoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076048/mark-balhoff), add spaces around the ampersands.

Comment: You already use `Rows`, you can remove the `EntireRow` and just use `Worksheets("Exhibit").Rows(start_row & ":" & end_row).Hidden = True`